# How to use a variable docker image in github-actions?

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am trying to write a custom github-action that runs some commands in a docker container but allows the user to select which docker container they are run in (i.e. so I can run the same build instructions across different versions of the runtime environment)

My gut instinct was to have my `.github/actions/main/action.yml` file as

```
name: 'Docker container command execution'
inputs:
  dockerfile:
    default: Dockerfile_r_latest
runs:
  using: 'docker' 
  image: '${{ inputs.dockerfile }}'
  args:
   - /scripts/commands.sh
```

However this errors with:
`##[error](Line: 7, Col: 10): Unrecognized named-value: 'inputs'. Located at position 1 within expression: inputs.dockerfile`

Any help would be appreciated !

### File References

My `.github/workflow/build_and_test.yml` file is:

```
name: Test Package

on: 
  [push, pull_request]

jobs:

  R_latest:

    name: Test on latest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
        name: Checkout project

      - uses: ./.github/actions/main
        name: Build and test
        with:
          dockerfile: Dockerfile_r_latest
```

And my Dockerfile `.github/actions/main/Dockerfile_r_latest` is:

```
FROM rocker/verse:latest
ADD scripts /scripts
ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "-c" ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Interesting approach! I'm not sure if it's possible to use expressions in the `image` field of the action metadata. I would guess that the only fields that can take expressions instead of hardcoded strings are the `args` for the image so that the `inputs` can be passed.

For reference this is the `args` section of the `action.yml` metadata.
https://help.github.com/en/articles/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#args

I think there are other ways to achieve what you want to do. Have you tried using the `jobs.<job_id>.container` syntax? That allows you to specify an image that the steps of a job will run in. It will require that you publish the image to a public repository, though. So take care not to include any secrets.

For example, if you published your image to Docker Hub at `gowerc/r-latest` your workflow might look something like this:

```
name: Test Package

on: 
  [push, pull_request]

jobs:

  R_latest:

    name: Test on latest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: gowerc/r-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
        name: Checkout project

      - name: Build and test
        run: ./scripts/commands.sh
```

ref: https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer

Alternatively, you can also specify your image at the step level with `uses`. You could then pass a command via `args` to execute your script.

```
name: my workflow
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Check container
        uses: docker://alpine:3.8
        with:
          args: /bin/sh -c "cat /etc/alpine-release"
```

ref: https://help.github.com/en/github/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-a-docker-hub-action

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@peterevans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11934042/peterevans) answer, I would add there's a 3rd option where you can use a simple `docker run` command and pass any `env` that you have defined.

That helped to solve 3 things :

- Reuse a custom docker image being build within the steps for testing actions. It seems not possible to do so with `uses` as it first tries to pull that image that doesn't exist yet in a `Setup job` step that occurs before any steps of the job.
- This specific image can also be stored in a private docker registry
- Be able to use a variable for the docker image

My workflow looks like this :

```
name: Build-Test-Push
on:
push:
    branches:
    - master
env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_REGISTRY }}
    ECR_REPOSITORY: myproject/myimage
    IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}

jobs:

build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checking out
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
        ref: master

    - name: Login to AWS ECR
    id: login-ecr
    uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build
    run: |
        docker pull $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY || true
        docker build . -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest

    - name: Test
    run: |
        docker run $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest /bin/bash -c "make test"

    - name: Push
    run: |
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. The Docker image to use is passed to a `cibuild` shell script that takes care of pulling the right image.

GitHub workflow file:

```yaml
name: 'GH Actions CI'

on:
  push:
    branches: ['*master', '*0.[0-9]?.x']
  pull_request:
    # The branches below must be a subset of the branches above
    branches: ['*master', '*0.[0-9]?.x']

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      fail-fast: true
      matrix:
        include:
          - FROM:     'ubuntu:focal'
          - FROM:     'ubuntu:bionic'
          - FROM:     'ubuntu:xenial'
          - FROM:     'debian:buster'
          - FROM:     'debian:stretch'
          - FROM:     'opensuse/leap'
          - FROM:     'fedora:33'
          - FROM:     'fedora:32'
          - FROM:     'centos:8'

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        # We must fetch at least the immediate parents so that if this is
        # a pull request then we can checkout the head.
        fetch-depth: 2

    # If this run was triggered by a pull request event, then checkout
    # the head of the pull request instead of the merge commit.
    - run: git checkout HEAD^2
      if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}

    - name: Run CI
      env:
        FROM: ${{ matrix.FROM }}
      run: script/cibuild
```

Bash script `script/cibuild`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

docker run --name my-docker-container $FROM script/custom-script.sh
docker cp my-docker-container:/usr/src/my-workdir/my-outputs .
docker rm my-docker-container

echo "cibuild Done!"
```

Put your custom commands in `script/custom-script.sh`.